# VBA, Extracting Specific words from txt document containing html and making a list of them in excel

Tags: html, vba, tags, find

Im having an issue trying to extract certain information out of an html file saved on my computer. I need vba code to
1) open this txt containing html, 
2) find the a "Strong" tag containing the word heater, and the td tag afterwords contains the phrase I need
4)Copy it and past in into C2

There is more information that I need from this html file however the format is the same there is the tag  item, and in the  tag is the specific info I need.

I am very new to programing and I can usually find things on forums and piece it together however this is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is read in a file and then do pattern matching. The HTML should be able to be opened using a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). I'm not positive on that, but it's worth a try. Then, you just need to separate the document out word for word and do pattern matching with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse it as xml. In following there are assumptions about the document structure (table element is sibling which follows the strong element), but this can get you started:

```
' Add reference to Microsoft XML
Sub ExtractFromHtml()
    Dim XMLDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim strongNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim strongNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim nextNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strongValue As String
    Set XMLDOC = New DOMDocument
    XMLDOC.Load ("C:\Where\your\doc\is\test.html")

    Set strongNodes = XMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("strong")
    For i = 0 To strongNodes.Length - 1
        Set strongNode = strongNodes.Item(i)
        If InStr(strongNode.XML, "Heater") > 0 Then ' <strong> with "Heater"
            Set nextNode = strongNode.NextSibling
            While nextNode.nodeName <> "table" ' first table *after* <string>
                Set nextNode = nextNode.NextSibling
            Wend
            Set nextNode = nextNode.FirstChild ' <tr>
            Set nextNode = nextNode.FirstChild ' <td>  should be the one you want 
        End If
    Next i
    Set strongNode = strongNodes.nextNode

End Sub
```